# Looping through an array to div?

Tags: javascript, html, list

I'm trying to add a p element containing a single month in this string to a div with the id of "write". How do I get this loop to run through the list of strings and add them to the div?

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October","November", "December"];
var element = document.getElementById("write").innerHTML = months;
for (var i = 0; i <= months; i++) {
var para = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode(i);
}
```

I don't understand why it isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rtx4hp9s/1

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're totally misunderstanding how to use arrays, you need to go back to your tutorials and study this.

You need to use `months.length` as the limit of the array, not just `months`. You should use `<`, not `<=` in the test, because otherwise you'll go past the end of the array. And in the text node you should put `months[i]`, not just `i`. Then you need to make the text node a child of the paragraph. You can't set the `innerHTML` of an element to an array; you should be adding the paragraphs as children of the element.

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var element = document.getElementById("write");
for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var text = document.createTextNode(months[i]);
  para.appendChild(text);
  element.appendChild(para);
}
```

```html
<div id="write"></div>
```